# Routing between two networks on linux?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I got stuck with one problem I cant find solution. I have linux pc with two NIC. first nic (eth1) is connected to public ip (probably switch or whatever, doesnt really mater) so eth1 is connected to wan and another eth0 that I connected to switch and make it a lan nic.
configuration:

eth1 ip address 88.200.1xx.xxx //xxx's are cuz of security reasons
eth0 ip address 192.168.1.1

wan ------> [eth1 (linux PC) eth0]<---->[switch]<----> [eth1 (PC1)]

Now I want to connect this two networks, so PC1 can access linux PC and wan. I think I know how to do it but I cant confiugre it right. This is what I tried:

1. I turend on ip forwarding (for sure)
2. I set eth1 default gw to the right ip on the wan
3. I tried to set eth0 default gw to the same ip (but i couldnt)

What or how can I do this, I was trying with linux route command, but I got stuck. 
Please help.

Comment: You really don't describe the problem. What makes you think you couldn't configure it right? What went wrong?

Comment: Not sure how others missed this, but you'll need NAT for this to work. So how did you configure iptables? You don't tell us any information as to what doesn't work. If you can ping your eth1 interface, then the only thing that remains for you to talk to the internet and get responses back is some NAT.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have 2 NICs on a Linux box, both configured with IP's you don't have to add a route from one network to another. That will be done automatically.

Add a default gateway address on the WAN NIC. **Do not do this in the configuration of the LAN NIC.**

Then enable forwarding in the kernel:

```
echo 1 >> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

To make it auto-set this value on boot uncomment this line in`/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then set up some rules in iptables to perform the natting and forwarding:

```
# Always accept loopback traffic
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# We allow traffic from the LAN side
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT

######################################################################
#
#                         ROUTING
#
######################################################################

# eth0 is LAN
# eth1 is WAN

# Allow established connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# Masquerade.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
# fowarding
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# Allow outgoing connections from the LAN side.
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

that should do it.

Comment: Thank you very much buddy... Actually I did this, but my problem was with route tables... I thought route tables work differently, so I set them up wrong. What I thought was: NIC in route table meant source nic of the traffic, but then somebody told me interface in route table is destination interface :D :D

Comment: What are the equivalent with UFW?

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one default gateway, so only set one.

To route traffic across the other interface, you need to set a persistent static route and bind it to that interface.

Comment: how i set this route? you mean static route from 192.168.1.0 to wan?

Comment: He shouldn't need to do anything special to route traffic across the other interface. The interface route that's made automatically should be sufficient.

Comment: It doesnt work... I tried just configured iptables to do nat but it doesnt work...dohhh

Answer (score 1):

I have to do this, very rarely, when setting up ancient routers connected via ethernet to my netbook. My answer, which I found in my [blog](https://jcomeau.com/blog/2012-09-26-0555Z) from September 2012, is very much like [Goez's](https://serverfault.com/users/87658/goez) but simpler:

On the router: `route add default gw 192.168.42.123` (the eth0 IP of the Linux box)

On the Linux box: `sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"`, followed by
`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE`