# How to "bridge" two separate peer-to-peer subnets together?

Tags: linux, networking, router, subnet, linksys

Here is what the network looks like:

```
Network A is 192.168.116.X , subnet 255.255.255.0  
Network B is 12.32.8.X , subnet 255.255.255.0
```

There are no routers present in either of the network schemes. All routing is done through unmanaged switches and hubs. Both networks are peer-to-peer and do not rely on DHCP. All machines have static IPs.

I need any machine on Network B to be able to reach any node on Network A

Comment: Please explain more how your environment looks like.

Comment: Are both networks already behind the same router?

Comment: I added more clarity to the question above. Let me know if more info is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the gateway for each network you add a route to the other subnet.

Answer (score 0):

You should have PC that connect both networks. Next you need to setup forwarding on this PC. For manual you can use this tread - [Routing between two networks on linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/453254/routing-between-two-networks-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a cheap router, take one pc and add one more network card. 
1 card will has 192.168.116.X
the other one will have 12.32.8.X

you have to make ip forwarding ( i recommend you to install ubuntu)