# How to hook an Ethernet over USB connection up to the host-Network?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, usb, interface, arch-linux

I have a single board computer that I want to hook up to my lan/internet connection. The SBC doesn't have an Ethernet port, only a an embedded wireless chip which currently isn't working. But it does have USB and I figured that it should be possible to connect it via ethernet over USB to my workstation and then do some kind of bridging/forwarding. I'm using a Beagle Bone Black Wireless and (currently) Arch Linux ARM am33x for the "client". Workstation is Fedora 23. The ethernet over USB is working, i can SSH into the SBC. However I didn't manage to get from the SBC to my local network or Internet.

## A list of things I already tried:

### Exhibit a:

This allows me to SSH into the client.

**Configuration/Commands on the Client:**

```
modprobe g_ether
```

**netctl configuration:**

```
Description='USB ethernet connection'

Interface=usb0

Connection=ethernet

IP=static

Address=('192.168.7.2/24')

DNS=('8.8.8.8')

#Gateway=('192.168.1.1')

## For IPv6 autoconfiguration

IP6=stateless
```

**Configuration on the workstation:**

```
ifconfig enp0s29u1u2 192.168.7.1
```

### Exhibit b:

I tired this to connect the two interfaces (`enp0s29u1u2` is the Eth over usb side interface and `enp6s0` faces my local network and also the internet); the following code is executed on the Workstation.
I found this here: [Routing between two networks on linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/453254/routing-between-two-networks-on-linux)

```
echo 1 >> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s29u1u2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp6s0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD -i enp6s0 -o enp0s29u1u2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables --append FORWARD -i enp0s29u1u2 -o enp6s0 -j ACCEPT
```

First I left the IP addresses as they were `192.168.1.0/24` for the Lan and `192.168.7.0/24` for the Ethernet over USB network. But I couldn't reach my gateway or anything beneath my workstation. I also tried to give the Beagle Bone an `192.168.1.*` address which also didn't help. *I'm probably missing something here. Routing maybe?*

### Exhibit c:

I also tried to set up a bridge between the interfaces.

**Netctl config on beaglebone was set to something like this:**

Description='USB ethernet connection'

```
Interface=usb0

Connection=ethernet

IP=static

Address=('192.168.1.210/24')

DNS=('8.8.8.8')

Gateway=('192.168.1.1')

## For IPv6 autoconfiguration

IP6=stateless
```

**Commands(Workstation):**

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 enp6s0 enp0s29u1u2
ifconfig br0 192.168.1.202 (or some random free address)
```

I had to do `route add default gw 192.168.1.1` in order to regain Internet access on my workstation. I also did it on the beaglebone, but it also didn't
 work out. I'm not sure but as im understanding the network bridge it should behave like i just hooked up the device to an ethernet switch(i.e. the members of the network can communicate as if the bridge wasn't there; but it apparently needs a seperate ip so i'm a bit confused, please give me a hint).

### Core Question:

Is there some manual routing required to integrate the Beaglebone in the lan and get internet access or something else maybe? Thank you for any hints! Hackarounds are also apprectiated as i'm looking for a temporal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `echo 1 >> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

But it should be `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Gateway is commented out `#Gateway=('192.168.1.1')` in one of your options.

You would need to do `ip route add default via 192.168.1.1` on the single board computer so it knows where to send internet traffic. (Where `192.168.1.1` is the IP of the device with `ip_forward` turned on.)

Comment: I know about the comment and i tried it commented and uncommented (with route add default gw 192.168.1.1). I just copied a version to provide an example. You mean on the Workstation, right? And with the bridge or just the iptables? Thanks for your answer! I'll try!

Comment: have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks again, but it still didn't work. Do I need the brigdge or iptables or just the forwarding enabled? Or something additional on the workstation?

Comment: You shouldn't need bridge, just iptables and ip forwarding. The ip forwarding tells your workstation to forward on the traffic.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. Turns out I failed to notice two things: Fedora 23 doesn't use iptables any more, its firewalld, but there is a legacy package, `iptables-services`. So then I had to disable firewalld and enable iptables. Secondly, there were rules in the iptables that rejected all forwarded an input traffic.

Comment: Glad it's working :-)